# Unable to access user control public properties and events directly on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have public properties and event defined in user control but I am not able to access the property directly but able to after type casting.

In user control

```
public string FromDate { 
get { return txtFromDate.Text; } 
set { txtFromDate.Text = value;} 
}
```

In aspx page

```
<uc:DateControl id="dcFromDate" runat="server"/>
```

In page code behind

```
dcFromDate.FromDate = "12/2/2014"; //not working
(dcFromDate as DateControl).FromDate = "12/2/2014"; // working
```

Comment: In your geter/setter you have return txtFromdate.Text I am assuming that is a textbox in which when you attempt to set it your setting the textbox object = to a string.

Comment: shouldn't it be `set { txtFromDate.Text = value; }`?

Comment: how is the property dcFromDate typed? It should be a protected DateControl dcFromDate in your .designer file. Maybe it uses a different Type?

Comment: How is your UserControl Registered on the Page?

Comment: Can you share the bits of the class definition too?